# Python - Socket Communication, multiple messages

Tags: python, sockets, communication

I'm stuck on this socket communication, I've looked everywhere but I haven't found an answer yet.

THE PROBLEM: I can only send 1 message from the client before it either gives me an error or ends the script.
I need to be able to send multiple messages to the server.

The server side (shown below) should be fine:

```
# Echo server program
import socket
import time
import os

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

today = time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
logFileName = "log - " + today + ".txt"


HOST = '10.0.0.16'                                                          
PORT = 8080                                                                 # Reserve a port for your service
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024                                                          
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)                       # Create a socket object
s.bind((HOST, PORT))                                                        # Bind to the port


def print_write(text):
    log.write(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "  |  " + text)
    log.write("\n")
    print text


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


if os.path.isfile(logFileName) is True:
    log = open(logFileName, 'a+')
    print_write("[SERVER] Log for " + today + " already exists.")
    print_write("[SERVER] Starting comms")
else:
    print "[SERVER] Log doesn't exist"
    log = open(logFileName, 'a+')                                           # Create file -> log - %date%.txt
    print_write("[SERVER] Log created")


while True:
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data == "Comms Shutdown":
        print_write("------ REMOTE SHUTDOWN ------")
        conn.close()
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        print_write("[COMMS] " + str(addr) + " says: " + data)

log.close()
```

Sorry if it's very messy and confusing but i don't have much time to finish this project, if you have any question just ask.

For the client side I don't have much but here, I'll give you this:

```
import socket

HOST = '10.0.0.16'          # The remote host
PORT = 8080                 # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    msg = raw_input()
    s.sendall(msg)
    print msg
```

I know it doesn't work, it's just to give you an idea of what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your server code only calls recv one time before looping again, you should use a while loop or something like that to call `recv` multiple times before opening a new connection..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you only read the first message from each open connection before moving on to the next. The `accept()` methods waits for a new connection and gives you the information needed when a new one comes in. the `recv()` method on the other hand, receives data from a existing connection and waits if there is none. If you want to receive multiple messages from a single client, you can just wait for the first connection and then wait for data with `recv()`. This could look like this:

```py
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if data == "Comms Shutdown":
        print_write("------ REMOTE SHUTDOWN ------")
        conn.close()
        raise SystemExit
    else:
        print_write("[COMMS] " + str(addr) + " says: " + data)
```

If you want to be able to also manage multiple clients, you will have to create a thread for each one from a while loop waiting for new connections. This is a bit more complicated:

```py
def client_handler(conn):
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if data == "Comms Shutdown":
            print_write("------ REMOTE SHUTDOWN ------")
            conn.close()
            raise SystemExit  
            # this will kill the server (remove the line above if you don't want that)
        else:
             print_write("[COMMS] " + str(addr) + " says: " + data)

while True:
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=(conn, ))
    recv_thread.start()
```

All this code is untested. Be aware, that I omitted the logging part and the socket creation part as well as all imports.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Great, thank you very much.